# How to read last line in csv file in java when it is different than other lines

Tags: java

I wrote code to read strings from a csv file. Everything works as intended until I reach the last line of the file (the lone q). My program then hangs up and does not seem to know how to handle the last line. I need my program to read everything into a string including the q for use in other classes.

csv file is as follows:

```
u,ADMHops,ADM Grace Hopper,12498,P@55w0Rd,8
u,average-joe,Joe Jones,12377,123,3
b,Googlebot,searchEngine,Sergey Brin,12345678,2
b,cw1noonbot,malicious,Some Rascal,asdf1234AAA@@@,6
q
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AccountTester {
public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    scnr.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
    String str1 = "p", str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;

    while(scnr.hasNext()){

        str1 = scnr.next();

        if(Objects.equals(str1, "q")) {
            break;
        }

        str2 = scnr.next();
        str3 = scnr.next();
        str4 = scnr.next();
        str5 = scnr.next();
        str6 = scnr.next();

        System.out.print(str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3 + " " + str4 + " " + str5 + " " + str6);       

    }
    System.out.print(str1);
    scnr.close();
}

}
```

I expect:

```
u ADMHops ADM Grace Hopper 12498 P@55w0Rd 8
u average-joe Joe Jones 12377 123 3
b Googlebot searchEngine Sergey Brin 12345678 2
b cw1noonbot malicious Some Rascal asdf1234AAA@@@ 6
q
```

but I get:

```
u ADMHops ADM Grace Hopper 12498 P@55w0Rd 8
u average-joe Joe Jones 12377 123 3
b Googlebot searchEngine Sergey Brin 12345678 2
b cw1noonbot malicious Some Rascal asdf1234AAA@@@ 6
```

Comment: Is there a return character `\n` after the q?

Comment: No there does not appear to be. I added one to the file just to see what would happen and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Objects; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AccountTester { 
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr;
        try {
            File file = new File("/path/to/your/file/input.csv");
            scnr = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Input file not found");
            return;
        }

        scnr.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
        String str1 = "p", str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;

        while(scnr.hasNext()){

            str1 = scnr.next();

            if(str1.equals( "q")) {
                System.out.println(str1);
                break;
            }

            str2 = scnr.next();
            str3 = scnr.next();
            str4 = scnr.next();
            str5 = scnr.next();
            str6 = scnr.next();

            System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3 + " " + str4 + " " + str5 + " " + str6);       

        }

        scnr.close();
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be using `System.in` to read a file in the first place. Pass a `File` object to your `Scanner` and it should work. Don't forget to change the file path in your solution.

Also you should use `String.equals()` to compare strings in Java.

Comment: You want to swap `break` and the print statement.

Comment: I just tried what you recommended. Unfortunately I am still getting stuck and does not print the q.

Comment: Try `str1.equals("q")` instead of `Objects.equals(str1, "q")`.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately that is not working as well. I am pretty beginner level with java, but if I am reading the debug correctly it seems like the q is not being read into str1 at all. I could be misunderstanding though.

Comment: Changed the entire answer, check it out.

Comment: That does indeed print the q. I guess I did forget to mention that I was running it with run configurations having an input file, but either way this seems to do the trick. Much thanks!